# It is possible to use a HDMI card with OpenBSD

Tags: openbsd, hdmi

Is it possble to use a HDMI card with OpenBSD? I have a home server but at the moment I have only a TV with an HDMI entry. I would like to use OpenBSD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the chip on your card.

Support for Intel and Radeon is quite good: quoting one of the developers from [a recent mailing list thread](http://marc.info/?l=openbsd-misc&m=141987838304054&w=2):

```
If you're after acceleration for now it is <= Haswell for 
Intel (excluding Bay Trail) or <= Northern Islands for Radeon.
```

See also the relevant man pages: [`intel(4)`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man4/intel.4?query=intel) and `radeon(4)`. Nvidia is still not supported (there is port of the Nouveau driver) and blobs are a big no-no in OpenBSD-land.

The `azalia(4)` audio driver doesn't currently support codecs that are intended for HDMI connectivity.

Comment: Links to [`radeon(4)`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man4/radeon.4) and [`azalia(4)`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man4/azalia.4) which I wasn't allowed to include in the post.